# Date field inside the object is getting type of Long

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

The LocalDateTime field that I sent as Long type from Spring boot, is not deserialized in angular and it comes as long although Date is kept as type.

Is there a global deserialize setting for this in Angular? I want to do it without writing new Date(field_name).

*JSON data sent from Spring Boot*

```
..."field_1":1666256336000...
```

*Angular model*

```
export class Object1 {
        field_1: Date;
}
```

*Angular Service Method*

```
method_name(){
    return this.getHttp().get<Object1>(..urls..);
}
```

*We call the method*

```
this.service.method_name().pipe().subscribe((data: Object1) => {
            console.log(data.field_1)
        });
```

*Output like this*

```
1666256336000
```

Comment: Can I suggest you update the question in a couple of ways? I think they'll help you get answers. Here are the suggestions: 1. It doesn't matter where the JSON comes from, so I'd remove Spring Boot from the question entirely. 2. I'd update the title to directly ask what you're asking: "Is there a global JSON deserializing setting for converting specific field from number to Date?" 3. I'd explain what you mean by "...although Date is kept as type..." The JSON doesn't show anything indicating that `field_1` is a date. Good luck!

Comment: I don't work in Angular (yet?), but [interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) look like they might be one approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need [an Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) that would intercept the data incoming, take the Long you received and which represents a timestamp in milliseconds and transform the data into a Date object.

Your Interceptor would have to use the [new Date(value) constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) of the JS Date Object, which can take a timestamp in milliseconds.

EDIT: Something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DateFormatInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(httpRequest).pipe(
       map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
          let formatted = response.clone();
          for(let key in formatted){
             if(key == "date1" || key == "date2" || key == "date3"){
                formatted[key] = new Date(formatted[key]);
             }
          }
          return formatted;
       }
     );
  }
}
```

Then you have of course to provide this interceptor.

Comment: I added an example code